# Table column is squashed with scollbars

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I know this has been asked much the same before but no answers seem to apply to me.

I have a table inside a DIV container. When 5 rows are inside the table, scrollbars on the the x-axis are shown, however, you can see that the content in column 1 is squashed.

The width of both columns 2 & 3 are fixed, but 1 is allowed to adjust itself to the correct width. When I try to measure the width of the text (by copying it to a span) it is not the correct size, otherwise I would just tally up the width of the 3 columns and adjust the table width.

How would I prvent the squashing or get the table width? jQuery tells me the width and outer width are zero...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a css rule to the elements in the column white-space: nowrap;

otherwise can you js fiddle it or provide a link?

Comment: Thank you so much - I've been stuck for weeks on this!

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing a fiddle I can only assume that you're explicitly setting cell/row heights (**column** and **2/3** get rendered on the same line in the title); allowing for it to be flexible would work without cropping the content. It would also accomodate for longer titles.

If that's not an option, set `overflow:hidden;text-overflow:ellipsis;` on the cells; that will cause for them to render like "Doctor Who: Attack of the..." if the content just doesn't fit.